# camel-spring-ws with sslContextParameters

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, apache-camel, spring-ws

I am consuming a SOAP service using Apache camel Spring-ws component. Things are working fine till the time service was hosted with HTTP protocol.

To work with HTTPS, i tried setting keystore and truststore jks as below

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",keyStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",keyStorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",trustStorePath);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",trustStorePassword);
```

it fails with the error unable to find the certificate.
Whereas the same properties and jks are working fine when i consume a RESTFull service using Http component.

I could see that the only option currently available is

```
<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters">
<camel:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
    <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
        password="changeit" />
</camel:keyManagers>
<camel:trustManagers>
    <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
        password="password" />
</camel:trustManagers>
```

Is there way i can configure it pragmatically, i followed the link below

http://camel.apache.org/http4.html#HTTP4-UsingtheJSSEConfigurationUtility

```
KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
ksp.setResource("/users/home/server/keystore.jks");
ksp.setPassword("keystorePassword");

KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
kmp.setKeyPassword("keyPassword");

SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

HttpComponent httpComponent = getContext().getComponent("https4",      HttpComponent.class);
httpComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
```

Supported components are

1. HTTP4
2. Jetty
3. AHC
4. Netty
5. Cometd
6. FTP2
7. IRC
8. Mail
9. MINA 2

But how do i set it for camel-spring-ws component ? Is it currently a limitation with Camel?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace ?

Comment: There are no stacktrace as things are working fine. Just that it's not configurable through java code.